# Multiple designs for single ASP.NET site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

We want to have multiple and entirely different designs running on a single ASP.NET site. All these sites should share single user identity database and other data but be entirely independent in look and feel one from another.

To achieve this, we decided to use AngularJS client-side rendering consuming all data in REST services directly from the site's Web API. However, we get then various CORS errors in browsers due to alleged unsafe redirects.

We know how to modify server to fix these CORS errors. But we are unsure, if selected approach is valid and safe for a long term in principle. Maybe such task should be solved by other means than pure JS client approach?

Comment: Why mention CORS if you already know a workaround? Focus on the real issue at hand.

Comment: We are not sure, if it is safe to enable CORS and go this way or there exist other, more solid approaches.

Comment: For instance, one can imagine server based clone sites written in PHP or ASP.NET or any other technology, which will consume master site WEB API on server-side level and then render client pages without so massive JS usage. Will it be preferable in terms of development effort, security and maintenance?

Comment: That's really up for your team to decide what is appropriate for your situation. We can't decide these things for you.

Comment: Thank you, @mason. It means for us that there are no predefined preferences in either approach and we have no prohibitive arguments against any mentioned design. This is actually what we wanted to know.